# Multiple crawlers database connection in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Let's say I instantiate multiple crawlers for the same URL. They write URLs that are processed to MySQL database. Before processing URL, they check in database if record for that page exists, so it wouldn't process already processed page again.

Here is the catch, there should exist some kind of lock, so that only one of them can read or write from that specific table, if my logic is right. So, I instantiated only one database connection (JDBC) for them to use. Still, I am unsure if this is right thing to do.

So my question is: do statements executed from single database connection run sequentially(are they queued) or does this depend on database engine it's configuration.

Comment: Does each crawler run on its own thread?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: you can use MyIsam i think, this will lock table. other option if all threads runs within same application you can develop a Q approach that all crawler threads adds URLs in Q and Q checks and inserts in DB

Answer (score 0):

> So, I instantiated only one database connection (JDBC) for them to use. Still, I am unsure if this is right thing to do.

I recently face some similar situation. I choose to have one JDBC connection only and use a `Lock` for sharing this connection between threads.

Some kind of status flag is needed to indicate that one particular URL is being processed.

Check my simple snippet below illustrating the previous points.

> do statements executed from single database connection run sequentially(are they queued) or does this depend on database engine it's configuration.

To eliminate any doubts, let your Java code ensure that statements run sequentially. This will put away any headcahes coming from unexpected errors later.

#### Code snippet

**CrawlerThread.java**

```
public class CrawlerThread extends Thread {

     public void run() {
         String url=null;
         try {
            String url = urlDao.getNextUrlToProcess();

            if (url!=null) {
                // Process URL here...
            }
         } catch(Exception e) {
              // Handle exception here...
         } finally {
            urlDao.markUrlAsFetched(url);
         }
     }
}
```

**UrlDAO.java**

```
public class UrlDAO {

      public String getNextUrlToProcess() {
          Connection jdbcConnection = null;
          String url = null;

          try {
              jdbcConnection = connectionManager.acquireSharedConnection();

              // Perform query to get next url
              // SELECT url FROM urls WHERE status = 'NEED_FETCH' LIMIT 1
              ResultSet rs = ...
              if (rs.next()) {
                  url = ...

                  // Mark url as being processed
                  setUrlStatus(jdbcConnection, url, 'BEING_FETCHED');
              }
          } catch(Exception e) {
              // Handle exception here...
          } finally {
              connectionManager.releaseSharedConnection();
          }

          return url;
      }

      public void markUrlAsFetched(String url) {
          Connection jdbcConnection=null;

          try {
              jdbcConnection = connectionManager.acquireSharedConnection();

              setUrlStatus(jdbcConnection, url, 'FETCHED');
          } catch(Exception e) {
              // Handle exception here...
          } finally {
              connectionManager.releaseSharedConnection();
          }
      }

      private void setUrlStatus(Connection jdbcConnection, String url, String newStatus) {
          // UPDATE urls SET status = ? WHERE url = ?
          if (url!=null) {
             ...
          }
      }
}
```

**ConnectionManager.java**

```
/**
 *
 * The ConnectionManager opens, closes and shares a JDBC connection among the different threads.
 *
 */
public class ConnectionManager {
     private Lock connectionLock = new ReentrantLock();
     private Connection sharedConnection = ... 

     public Connection acquireSharedConnection() {
          connectionLock.lock();
          return sharedConnection;
     }

     public void releaseSharedConnection() {
          connectionLock.unlock();
     }
}
```